# Is it possible to change the default search engine with a Google Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have to develop an extension which adds a new search engine and sets it as default.

I have not found anything in https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/

Is it possible?

Comment: Has anything changed so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You [cannot set the default search engine to an extension-defined search engine](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=100495):

> Allowing an extension-added engine to be default is problematic because there's no clear fallback path for when the extension is uninstalled -- especially if the previous default (or worse, all other engines) are deleted first.  This could allow us to get into a "no engine as default" case which Chrome isn't prepared to handle.
>
> Chrome does support keywords directly, e.g. add a search engine for Wikipedia and make the keyword "w", and "w foo" will search Wikipedia for foo.  Perhaps you can use this native capability as a workaround?

You can add a new keyword-based search provider via the [`chrome.omnibox`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox.html) API (but you cannot make it the default).

Answer (score 3):

It is now possible to create a new search engine and even set it as default; however, the method to do so it only available on Windows according to [Chrome docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/settings_override):

> Settings overrides are a way for extensions to override selected Chrome settings. The API is available only on Windows.

The gist is as follows: **if your extension's Web Store listing is associated to the verified domain used in search**, you can specify it in the manifest.

That means you can only do so **if you control the search engine page** to the point of being able to [verify it for your account in Webmaster Tools](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35179).

The following is a minimal configuration:

```
"chrome_settings_overrides": {
  "name": "Example search",
  "keyword": "example",
  "search_url": "https://example.com/s?={searchTerms}",
  "favicon_url": "https://example.com/favicon.ico",
  "encoding": "UTF-8",
  "default": true
},
```